# Wordpress plugin failed to load other plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been using this plugin for few days.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-rss-feeds-widget/

This is the plugin that will be loaded as the first widget in my website sidebar. (I mean, at right corner)
For some reason, if there is no feed(RSS) from my URL that I provide, the other plugins is not getting loaded.

To explain this more deeper, I have set of 5 plugins like simplee rss feed widget, twitter plugin, mail chimp plugin etc..
If there is any error or problem in fetching RSS feed (I mean - problem with rss feed widget), the other plugins is not getting
loaded. Is there any way to check this and to show an error msg and load all the other plugins?

In other words, problem with simple rss widget, makes other plugin NOT TO WORK. Is there any way to load other plugin even if my simple rss feed widget fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the latest Wordpress version the plugin may not work even if it worked with other versions. As you see from your link it is not the most popular plugin nor it has any evidence to be working in the latest WP version. Consider searching for another plugin that does the same job.

Comment: No other option other than this suggestion, some sort of code wil help this overcome my problem? Thanks anyway for the quick reply.

Comment: I am afraid you will need to find the error in the code to fix the problem.